# Bind variable used in BEGIN/END gets cleared

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

This is a trivialized example so it is easy to reproduce, but the important thing is I need to set a variable based on a query using `into :someVariable from sometable where sometable.somecolumn = :y` and then leverage both variables after the BEGIN/END block.  **It seems referencing `:y` in the `where` causes it to be cleared.  Why does this happen?**

**I am more concerned with why does this happen than how to fix it.**  I have the work around of setting it with itself, but it seems like an odd side affect.  In the first example, I am not declaring a new variable named :y, so I would not think it is an issue with variable hiding.  Clearly the second example shows that I can set the value of the variable, and setting it is visible outside the scope of the block, which I would expect since the variable was declared outside the scope of the block.

```
clear screen;
variable x varchar2(10);
variable y varchar2(10); 

exec :y := 'YYY';

BEGIN
  select '1' into :x
  from dual
  where 'YYY' = :y;
END;
/

select :y from dual;
```

Output shows :y is cleared:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


:Y                             
--------------------------------
```

If I set :y with itself, the value is preserved:

```
clear screen;
variable x varchar2(10);
variable y varchar2(10); 

exec :y := 'YYY';

BEGIN
  select '1' into :x
  from dual
  where 'YYY' = :y;

  :y := :y;
END;
/

select :y from dual;
```

Output:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


:Y                             
--------------------------------
YYY
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Your test case seems to work as expected.

Comment: @BobC What version are you using?

Comment: Version: 12.1.0.2

Comment: @BobC What version of SQL Developer? I think this has something to do with the client.  I have tried when connected to different servers across 12g and 11c with same results.

Comment: I think this is this bug, same version of SQL Developer that I'm using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43501389/84206

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to SQL Developer 17.2.0.188 and it went away.

Appears to be this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43501389/84206