# SQL Developer Clears Bind Variable in Script

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am writing a script where the output from one procedure is needed for multiple later procedures. So, I need bind variables, not substitution variables. But, whenever the variable is used, it is cleared. That makes it impossible to use a variable's value more than once. The exact same script works in SQL*Plus. I have made a shortened script below that demonstrates the problem.

Is this a setting that can be changed in SQL Developer? Is this a bug? In my case, I am using SQL Developer version 4.1.5.21.78.

```
var x varchar2(1)
var y varchar2(1)
print x
print y
exec :x := 'Z';
exec :y := 'Z';
print x
print y
exec :x := :y;
-- Why did that last line clear y?
print x
print y
```

output

```
X
------


Y
------


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


X
-
Z

Y
-
Z

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


Y
-


X
-
Z
```

Comment: I don't see that in 4.2.0.17, the last two print commands both show Z. (The order you've shown the output doesn't match the code, but still...). I do see the problem in 4.1.5.21 too though, so it does look like a bug in that version. Upgrading seems like a workaround?

Comment: I think this might be another example of this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43401127/84206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in 4.1.5, and possibly other versions, that has been fixed by version 4.2.0.17.

`exec` is just a wrapper for an anonymous block, but using an explicit block instead also shows the problem:

```
begin
  :x := :y;
end;
/
```

I'm pretty sure I've seen this reported before, but the only example I can find [is this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43401127/266304); as that notes you can work around it by reassigning the value to itself:

```
begin
  :x := :y;
  :y := :y;
end;
/
```

or slightly less readably:

```
exec :x := :y; :y := :y;
```

It certainly appears to be a bug, but as it's fixed in the current release, [upgrading](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) seems like a sensible way to resolve it. Otherwise you'd need to raise a service request to Oracle - though I suspect they'd advise to upgrade anyway.

(I may have been thinking all the way back to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15064702/266304), but that seems to be a different problem as that example looks OK in 4.1.5. I can't see any bug reports in My Oracle Support, for either issues; but they aren't always published.)

Comment: I upgraded to 4.2.0.17.089.1709 and the problem went away. I had tried to work around by assigning it to a second variable first, but that didn't work because it was moving the problem to that new line. But I see how you put the two lines together in a block. That probably would have worked, but I should not have had to do it, and I have moved on. Thanks.